# High speed op-amp Bode plot logic problem

Tags: operational-amplifier

At 3:34 of the video he says high-speed op-amps suffer from the parasitic capacitance effect.

Why do we have parasitic capacitance on the minus leg, and not on the load?

What is special in high-speed op-amps that can cause that?

I'll be happy to have some op-amp model example to see this effect.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3Rh2cRuaBM&list=PLL0g1xo2bMz0yN-PXYVX6jIxilrtK45fR&index=5).

[image]

Comment: We do have parasitic capacitance on the load.  The difference is that the impedance driving the load is low, so the parasitic capacitance doesn't have the same effect as it does on the extremely high impedance input node.

Comment: Parasitic capacitances are present on both inputs of the operational amplifier. This is an interesting article : https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/input-capacitance-analog-circuits-how-to-compensate-capacitance-op-amps/

Comment: you have it everywhere; on the + terminal, but it's not part of the feedback loop going thru the output ; on the load, it is driven at lower impedance

Comment: Hello , Could you please give me an example to a High speed opamp who has this problem and low speed opamp who does not has this problem?

Comment: any op amp where the loop bandwidth ( = GBW / 2, in the video example) is higher than the frequency of the pole introduced into the feedback path

Comment: Hello Pete , the input parasitic capacitance comes from the opamp itself or the traces?
Thanks.

Comment: @Josh23, Both of them! Input capacities are generally given in the datasheets. Example (see input impedance) : https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa1654

Comment: Hello Vincent , i know that a trace is inductive by signal integrity rules, why opamp sees it a capacitative? how can i know what capacitance the trace will introduce to the OPAMP?

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor is two conductor plates sandwiched around an insulator.  The inputs of high-input-impedance op amps generally FET gates, which can behave very much like one of the plates of a capacitor

Comment: Hello , Could you please give me an example to a High speed opamp who has this problem and low speed opamp who does not has this problem?